# No Checkpoints geneated during YOLO training

Tags: windows, tensorflow, object-detection, yolo, darkflow

I am currently training my YOLO for custom object detection 
The training command is running successfully and the loss is around 60 @steps 145

But i am not able to see any chckpts in the chkp folder. 
Is that normal , should i wait ?

Comment: Can you please define to us first the number of classes of your custom training dataset and the batch number you use.